# Logs in Console / Disk Usage

Tags: big-sur, logs, console

With a modern version of macOS, like Big Sur, if you open Console, you see tonnes and tonnes of messages streaming as soon as you press "start".

I was wondering, it seems like the chatter from Kernel/Apps/Info/Debug logs is non-stop, and huge amounts of volume.

This all gets written to disk in `/var/log` as I understand, though, when I "Start" in Console, I see so much, I don't see the disk writes spike in Activity Monitor, how does this level of logging not peg the disk usage high?

Does it get discarded when not "streaming" in Console? Does it get cached in RAM then bulk written? What's the modern mechanism here? It seems the modern OS generates so much log detail that the disk should never sleep, though it seems to.

Comment: A few lines of text is going to be negligible in the overall scheme of things.

Comment: @Tetsujin, have you seen the output? it's bananas, it's like a stream of KB's of data

Comment: KBs…. that's the salient point, I think. Run into swap memory & your talking GB.

Comment: I also think the log data itself is compressed, too, thus taking up far less actual disk space.